# How to use getSelection with an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, getselection

I have been trying use the getSelection command to select highlighted text from an iframe and insert it into a variable. Using the follow code I could make this work a textarea.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function GetSelectedText () {
        var selText = "";
        if (window.getSelection) {
            if (document.activeElement && 
                    (document.activeElement.tagName.toLowerCase () == "textarea" ))
            {
                var text = document.activeElement.value;
                selText = text.substring (document.activeElement.selectionStart, 
                                          document.activeElement.selectionEnd);
            }
            else {
                var selRange = window.getSelection ();
                selText = selRange.toString ();
            }
        }


        else {
            if (document.selection.createRange) {
                var range = document.selection.createRange ();
                selText = range.text;
            }
        }

var highlight = selText;
        if (highlight !== "") {
            alert (highlight);
        } 
        if (highlight == "") {
            alert ("No string selected");
        }


    } </script>
<body >
<br /><br />
<textarea  onclick="GetSelectedText ()">Some text in a textarea element.</textarea>
</body>
```

But when I add the following line of code, it still won't execute in an iframe.

```
|| document.activeElement.tagName.toLowerCase () == "iframe"
```

How can I fix this so I can highlight a string from my iframe and have the script execute?

UPDATED:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var editorDoc;
    function InitEditable () {
        var editor = document.getElementById ("editor");

        if (editor.contentDocument)
            editorDoc = editor.contentDocument;
        else
            editorDoc = editor.contentWindow.document;

        var editorBody = editorDoc.body;

        if ('contentEditable' in editorBody) {
                // allow contentEditable
            editorBody.contentEditable = true;
        }
        else {  // Firefox earlier than version 3
            if ('designMode' in editorDoc) {
                    // turn on designMode
                editorDoc.designMode = "on";                
            }
        }
    }
    var iframe = document.getElementById('editor');
var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument;

function GetSelectedText () {
    var selText = "";
    if (innerDoc.getSelection) {
        if (innerDoc.activeElement && 
                (innerDoc.activeElement.tagName.toLowerCase () == "iframe"))
        {
            var text = innerDoc.activeElement.value;
            selText = text.substring (innerDoc.activeElement.selectionStart, 
                                      innerDoc.activeElement.selectionEnd);
        }
        else {
            var selRange = innerDoc.getSelection ();
            selText = selRange.toString ();
        }
    }


    else if
         (innerDoc.selection.createRange) {
            var range = innerDoc.selection.createRange ();
            selText = range.text;
        }


var highlight = selText;
    if (highlight !== "") {
        alert (highlight);
    } 
    if (highlight == "") {
        alert ("No string selected");
    }


}

</script>

<body onload="InitEditable ();">

<iframe onclick="GetSelectedText ()" id="editor"></iframe>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the script runs in the iframe's parent window. As such, you will need to use a different object than `document` to access it:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframeId');
var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument;
```

Comment: Hey I'm fairly new at javascript, where would I add those variables and what would I change in my script above? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You would want to replace pretty much every reference to "document" with "innerDoc". I think the same goes for replacing "window". Also noticed something else about your code: ``else { if (document.selection.createRange) {var range = document.selection.createRange();selText = range.text;}}`` is a bit verbose. You can just say ``else if (logical expression) {/*statement*/}``

Comment: Thanks again, I just edited my post with an updated code block, does that look correct now, or have I missed something?

Comment: Best thing to do is to try it out :) Have you heard of http://jsfiddle.net/? See if you can make one of those and I can help you out. Also, you're missing some brackets in lines 5-9